# Is it possible to integrate Moodle LMS with Django?

Tags: django, moodle, moodle-api

I've created a basic static website using Django and want to know is it possible to integrate Moodle LMS with my website.

If yes then tell me how should I do it?

Any help will be appreciated?

Comment: What kind of integration are you exactly after? Moodle has Web Services ( https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services ) which you can interact with, as an external client, and implement your given functionalities. Here's some more info: https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Using_web_services

Comment: So that I can use Moodle from my django website

Comment: Just like Moodle integration with wordpress